# how to update a column by combining two column values into one column in MySQL using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to update my existing column with concatenating two columns in a table using laravel migrations.

An example: I am having a column FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME and so many columns also. I want to concatenate these two columns with the name of FIRSTNAME only in between space.

So this is how it works in mysql:

```
SELECT CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS 'FIRSTNAME' FROM customer;
```

How we have to do this using laravel?

Right now Firstnames are displayed in one column and lastnames are displayed in another column. I have to update both the values into single column by concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an accessor in your model. You can check document [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) . In your case the follow function need to add to your model

```
public function getFirstNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $value. " ". $this->LASTNAME;
}
```